# Datagrid horizontal scrolling hides the content in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've tried to implement Zoom functionality in WPF application. While zooming, it should not affect default scrollviewer `DataGrid`. So, i used `LayoutTransform` in `DataGridRow`.

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" HeadersVisibility="None" SelectionMode="Extended" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
    <Slider Grid.Row="1" Minimum="0.5" Maximum="4" Value="1" Name="slider"/>
```

But, this code hides the DataGrid content after zoom and used Horizontal scrollviewer.

[Before/After Zoom and scroll the Horizontal Scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCbGR.png)

And then, tried with Style for DataGridCell but the issue not resolved.

```
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Did I missed any handling for this row elements hiding? Anyone please guide with this issue.

Updated for Full Code:

MainWindow.XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DatagridSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="600">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" HeadersVisibility="None" SelectionMode="Extended" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded">
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>
        <Slider Grid.Row="1" Minimum="0.5" Maximum="4" Value="1" Name="slider"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace DatagridSample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var items = new List<Dog>();
            items.Add(new Dog("Fido", 10));
            int count = 25;

            while(count != 0)
            {
                items.Add(new Dog("Spark", 20));
                count--;
            }
            (sender as DataGrid).ItemsSource = items;
        }
    }

    class Dog
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Name1 { get { return Name; } }
        public string Name2 { get { return Name; } }
        public string Name3 { get { return Name; } }
        public string Name4 { get { return Name; } }
        public string Name5 { get { return Name; } }
        public string Name6 { get { return Name; } }
        public string Name7 { get { return Name; } }
        public string Name8 { get { return Name; } }
        public string Name9 { get { return Name; } }
        public string Name10 { get { return Name; } }
        public string Name11 { get { return Name; } }
        public int Size { get; set; }

        public Dog(string name, int size)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Size = size;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to apply scale transform in first place? If there are texts you can simply change font size (but after some thoughts - you also have to resize columns). Applying transform on higher level (window?) feels more correct. Also, consider to prepare [mcve], it will be easier to answer.

Comment: Yes. I used Window in Higher level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying `ScaleTransform` for the `DataGrid` can be the solution However the scroll viewer is also zoomed during scale transform, so visibility of scroll viewer in `DataGrid` can be set to Hidden. Instead we can use `ScrollBar`.

Properties of Scroll viewer in data grid can be applied to scrollbar using  this:

```
SampleGrid.ItemsSource = new List<String>(lines);
SampleGrid.UpdateLayout();
Decorator border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(SampleGrid, 0) as Decorator;
ScrollViewer scrollViewer = border.Child as ScrollViewer;

//Horizontalbar is the scroll bar that i used.

Horizontalbar.Maximum = scrollViewer.ExtentWidth - scrollViewer.ViewportWidth;
Horizontalbar.ViewportSize = scrollViewer.ViewportWidth;
Horizontalbar.Value = scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
```

Also u can use the above snippet inside `ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged` Event to updated properties of scrollbars after resizing of window.

Use the following to scroll the `DataGrid` from the scrollbars inside `ScrollBar.Scroll` Event

```
private void Horizontalbar_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollBar bar = sender as ScrollBar;
    Decorator border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(SampleGrid, 0) as Decorator;
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = border.Child as ScrollViewer;
    scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(bar.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the ScaleTransform to the parent of the DataGrid i.e. Grid. The best solution would be to add the transform on the MainWindow, since you want to zoom in the whole application and not just the DataGrid

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but if we use LayoutTransform in Grid, ScrollViewer of DataGrid will also be zoomed.

Comment: you want to zoom only the content of the DataGrid? Then I would increase the FontSize. Just add a converter to the FontSize `{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource DoubleToFontSizeConverter}`

Comment: Thanks but it needs other handlings
Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148808/datagrid-horizontal-scrolling-hides-the-content-in-wpf/62149407?noredirect=1#comment109917222_62148808